# How to import existing AWS Amplify Back-End into an empty AWS Amplify project locally?

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I accidentally deleted my amplify frontend and created a new one. How do I import the existing amplify back end to the newly created amplify app project folder?

I followed the steps on the backend tab

1. `amplify init --appId ("ID OF YOUR NEW AMPLIFY APP")`.
2. Instead of `amplify add CATEGORY` here. I use `amplify update CATEGORY` here

Then `amplify push`.

But when I check the amplify app on the AWS console there still no backend integrated to it.

Am I doing correct?

*Version used:*

`"aws-amplify": "^2.1.0"`

Answer (score 8):

you can use the following command:

```
 amplify pull --appId someidgoeshere --envName dev
```

Comment: what is the envName used here? is the appId of the old app or the new app to which we need to import the old backend into?

Comment: --envName is a flag that informs what environment the code will be pulled from. --appId is an id of the app you want to pull the code locally. This command is not used for any migration