# How to restore accidentally deleted amplify project?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I accidentally deleted my amplify project from amplify console. I have the amplify backend folder in my git repo and an existing stack. If I make changes in graphql schema and execute `amplify push`, it is still working as expected. How do I restore this project in amplify?

I just want to make sure that restore process should not recreate all the aws resources like DynamoDB Tables, Pinpoint Projects, and so on.

I tried to refer and understand [github issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/10560) and [existing stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60365208/how-to-import-existing-aws-amplify-back-end-into-an-empty-aws-amplify-project-lo) but it is not clear how exactly do I restore amplify project. Should I create new app first with `amplify init`, and then execute `amplify pull --appId old_app_id --envName old_app_env`